# An ambiguous sentence from the music Dreamtale

Tags: pronouns, ambiguity

The whole sentence is

> As the last ship sailed towards the distant horizon, I sat there watching on a rock. My mind slowly drifting away, forming into my...dreamtale.

I can't figure out whether *I* was sitting on a rock or watching on a rock. It seems ambiguous, right?

Comment: In this context "watching on a rock" couldn't mean any thing else than "on a rock, watching"

Answer (score 1):

"I sat there watching on a rock" is unambiguous. You may be thinking that "watching on" can mean something like "gazing on" or "gazing at". But "watching" would be used transitively for that meaning: "watching a rock", never intransitively *"watching on a rock". The truly ambiguous sentence would be: "I sat there meditating on a rock".